# C++ changing values of an array inside a function by passing by reference

Tags: c++

The problem is that my pointer is always pointing to the same memory address, which makes it not behave like i want.

I want to store several values that in an array during a function but than also having to write them to the array present in main, by passing them as a reference so i don't have to take a return. Can anyone help me what is going wrong?

The code here works and you will see i get same addresses.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;



 void creatingarray(int starttemp2, int *arrayc2[], int nlength2, int step2){

    int *newtemp = new int;
    *newtemp = starttemp2;
    //cout << phead;

    cout << *newtemp << "   " << endl;

    for (int i=0; i < nlength2; i++){
        arrayc2[i] = newtemp;
        *newtemp = *newtemp + step2;

        cout << *arrayc2[i] << " " << arrayc2[i] <<" ";
        cout << *newtemp << " "<<endl;
    }

   for (int i=0;i<nlength2;i++)
    cout<< *arrayc2[i] << " ";

 }



int main()
{
  int step;
  int starttemp;
  int endtemp;



 cout << "Geef begin en eind temperatuur in om om te zetten met een bepaalde step";
 cout <<  "step:";
 cin >> step ;
 cout << "begintemperatuur in celsius: ";
 cin >> starttemp;
 cout << "eindtemperatuur in celius: ";
 cin >> endtemp;

 int nlength = (endtemp - starttemp) / step;
 int *arrayc[nlength];



 creatingarray(starttemp, arrayc, nlength, step);



/*
for (int accumulater = 0; accumulater < endtemp)
    cout << startemp;
    temperature S("test");*/

    cout << nlength;

   cout << "CELSIUS" << endl;
    for (int i=0;i<nlength;i++)
    cout<< *arrayc[i] << " ";


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You would be **much** better off using a `std::vector`.

Comment: first of all, your code will not compile because of `int *arrayc[nlength];`, you can't specify array size with a non const value.

Comment: @Zhou - Some compilers allow you to use a VLA from C, as an extension.

Comment: let's say start temperature is 5, end temperature is 7, and step is 1. Then number of values is 3. But (7 - 5)/1 = 2. As @BoPersson says, just use `std::vector`, unless you're forbidden to use it. Are you?

Comment: Let's just say I have no clue yet about vector! So I saw this as a good way of understanding better how this reference works. (Code compiles. Length of array is known upon initialisation). The step to be incorrect is not a problem as long as it is lower than the end temperature. that part of the code is ok. It's just how to get the memory location to write my array as reference correctly? I hope someone has an answer ( and yes so I will study up on vector)

Comment: Note that you don't need an array for printing out a systematic sequence of values. You can just compute them as you go. I'll post a *guess* about what you're trying to do, one way to do that. Strictly it's against SO rules: only answers to clear questions should be posted. A question/answer site, not a discussion site. But we can always delete. :)

Comment: Well what I try to do, is create an array temps, so that than I can use that array to recalculate the values to Fahrenheit and than output it to screen in a table.

Comment: So I want to build up the array based on starttemp an endtemp and a step to go forward. I know I can do this just in the code. But I want to shorten it specifically using the transfer by reference.

Answer (score 1):

This should hopefully get you going.

It may not be exactly what you intend to do, but what you intend to do is unclear.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int step;
    int starttemp;
    int endtemp;

    cout << "Geef begin en eind temperatuur in om om te zetten met een bepaalde step";
    cout << "step: ";
    cin >> step ;
    cout << "begintemperatuur in celsius: ";
    cin >> starttemp;
    cout << "eindtemperatuur in celius: ";
    cin >> endtemp;

    int const nlength = (step + endtemp - starttemp) / step;
    vector<int> arrayc( nlength );  // Important: don't use curly braces here! See comment by M.M.

    for( int i = 0;  i < nlength; ++i )
    {
        arrayc[i] = starttemp + i*step;
    }

    cout << nlength << " temperatures in CELSIUS:\n";
    cout << "\n";
    for( int i = 0;  i < nlength; ++i )
    {
        cout << arrayc[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, as I see this will exactly do what I need but in a different way :) I guess building up an array by reference  is not really possible in c++

Comment: It is possible, just not the way you are doing it.

Comment: `vector<int> arrayc{ nlength };` makes a vector with 1 element of value `nlength`  (the initializer list constructor is preferred)

Comment: @M.M: Thanks, fixing! Done. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with a variable-length array, you need to use `new[]` to allocate it before you can then read data into it.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

void creatingarray(int starttemp, int *arrayc, int nlength, int step)
{
    int newtemp = starttemp;        
    for (int i = 0; i < nlength; ++i)
    {
        arrayc[i] = newtemp;
        newtemp += step;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int step;
    int starttemp;
    int endtemp;

    cout << "Geef begin en eind temperatuur in om om te zetten met een bepaalde step." << endl;

    cout << "step: ";
    cin >> step;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    cout << "begintemperatuur in celsius: ";
    cin >> starttemp;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    cout << "eindtemperatuur in celius: ";
    cin >> endtemp;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    int nlength = (endtemp - starttemp) / step;
    int *arrayc = new int[nlength];

    creatingarray(starttemp, arrayc, nlength, step);

    cout << "Length " << nlength << endl;    

    cout << "CELSIUS" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < nlength; ++i)
        cout << arrayc[i] << " ";

    delete[] arrayc;
    return 0;
}
```

That being said, consider using `std::vector` instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

void creatingarray(int starttemp, std::vector<int> &arrayc, int nlength, int step)
{
    int newtemp = starttemp;        
    for (int i = 0; i < nlength; ++i)
    {
        arrayc.push_back(newtemp);
        newtemp += step;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int step;
    int starttemp;
    int endtemp;

    cout << "Geef begin en eind temperatuur in om om te zetten met een bepaalde step." << endl;

    cout << "step: ";
    cin >> step;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    cout << "begintemperatuur in celsius: ";
    cin >> starttemp;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    cout << "eindtemperatuur in celius: ";
    cin >> endtemp;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    int nlength = (endtemp - starttemp) / step;

    std::vector<int> arrayc;
    arrayc.reserve(nlength);

    creatingarray(starttemp, arrayc, nlength, step);

    cout << "Length " << nlength << endl;    

    cout << "CELSIUS" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < nlength; ++i)
        cout << arrayc[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```